# How to make false of a concise if statement do nothing

Tags: c#, if-statement

If I have:

```
logicBeingTested.isItTrue ? (doSomeStuffIfItsTrue) : (doSomeNothingIfFalse);
```

how do I make it so if my argument is true it only does the true half of that statement and not false. I tried doing this:

```
logicBeingTested.isItTrue ? (status = true) : ();
```

but that doesn't work. I know I can get around this by just doing an if statement but for curiosity's sake is it possible to give an answer of do nothing to an argument?

EDIT: my bool value 'status' from the OP was kinda misleading, I clarified what I want in the new edit

Comment: You tagged this [tag:if-statement]. You don't use an `if` statement at all here, but you should be.

Comment: I don't think a ternary operation is appropriate for this scenario - a normal `if` statement would be better.

Comment: Maybe `status = status`?  This is kind of an odd use of the conditional operator in the first place, do you do anything with the result of this operation?  It really sounds like this should be a normal `if` block.

Comment: @user1666620 Thanks didn't know this was called a ternary operation. I thought this was the same thing as an if statement, just more concise

Comment: For a boolean value which can only be true or false this makes absolutely no sense. A boolean has a standard value which is false if not changed. You can assign true to it or false, which is the same as assign true to it or do nothing (it stays false).

Comment: @David yeah it probably should be a normal if statement but I was just wondering if anything like this existed.

Comment: @PaulWeiland so the answer provided below would work correct?

Comment: A ternary expression must have a value. In this case you can choose `true` or `false` since the overall type is `bool` -- but you can't make the expression have *no* value (unless you think `default(bool?)` qualifies). A ternary expression is *not* a statement. Instead you're executing statements inside the expression, which is confusing and error-prone. Don't use this in production code.

Comment: You should avoid using the ternary operator with side-effects. Much better would be `status = logicBeingTested.isItTrue` or similar.

Comment: @Capn Jack It would work but there is absolutely no reason to do this if status is a boolean. Ternary operator is not designed to be used this way.

Comment: @PaulWeiland Sorry I think my OP was misleading with assign status values of true or false. I more so want this operation to do something if it's true and do nothing otherwise

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd say best to read is also best to write:

```
status |= logicBeingTested.isItTrue;
```

Just assigning a value (even if it's *useless*) *may* be as fast as a conditional instruction (which will probably involve `CMOV` and it's such minor optimization that should be probably ignored) and much more readable (IMO?).

If `status` is `Nullable<bool>` then simply go back to a plain `if` (edit: from comments it seems that it's not clear but it works with `bool?`, I just consider `if` more clear in this case. [Jeroen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39979237/how-to-make-false-of-a-concise-if-statement-do-nothing/39979311?noredirect=1#comment67239280_39979311) also noted that if `status` is a property it will involve a different behavior but we all have trivial property getters, right?).

```
if (logicBeingTested.isItTrue)
    status = true;
```

Note that `status |= logicBeingTested.isItTrue` is - on contrary to what it may be thought at first sight - equivalent to that `if` block, if `logicBeingTested.isItTrue` is `false` then `status` is unchanged (not `false`) then if it was `null` it's still `null`. This is (IMO) a good reason to use the `if` if you're working with `bool?`.

A note about your original code: [ternary operator ?:](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28.aspx) is usually used as a *function* and not because of *side effects* of its operands evaluation. It may be pretty misleading when reading that code.

---

Addendum for edited question: if you're not just assigning a value to a variable but you need to perform an action then *nothing* is more clear than an old if:

```
if (logicBeingTested.isItTrue)
    DoSomething();
```

Note that if `logicBeingTested` may be `null` then you may rewrite it as:

```
if (logicBeingTested?.isItTrue ?? false)
    DoSomething();
```

In this case if `logicBeingTested` you behave as `logicBeingTested.isItTrue` was `false`, to do the opposite just use `?? true`.

Comment: "and much more readable" -- You're entitled to your opinion, but it's not one that's universal, and I suspect not even common. I'd opt for `if (logicBeingTested.isItTrue) status = true;` over this.

Comment: @AdrianaRepetti Would you mind explaining a bit more about the ternary operator? Or linking me some literature about it? Just found out about them today from a colleague

Comment: @hvd I'd tend to agree "if" is clear but simply assigning also highlights that "status" is an OR between previous value and logicBeingTested.isItTrue (and "if" _hides_ this at first reading, IMO).

Comment: @CapnJack MSDN: [?: operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28.aspx)

Comment: Perhaps the code is a bad example, then: a `bool status;` variable doesn't have a name that indicates what the value means. I could see `anyItemNull |= item == null;`, since the way we would think about `anyItemNull` is `item1 == null || item2 == null || ...`, matching what you said. For a variable named `status`, regardless of whether it's a boolean, I wouldn't normally think of its value as a logical OR.

Comment: This answer shouldn't even be upvoted, IMHO. 1) OP asked to avoid using an if for the sake of the argument. 2) Only provided solution without an if doesn't support Nullable<bool>. 3) Most people won't recognize the bitwise OR assignment operator '|='; using it here is completely uncalled for, let alone it doesn't support nullables.

Comment: As an aside, `a |= b` is functionally different from `if (b) { a = true; }` if `a` is a property. This starts to matter when we're considering optimization (which shouldn't be the primary concern to begin with, of course).

Comment: @daniloquio 1) that's the _first part_ of the answer (and it works with nullables, you may want to **try**). I strongly think that an answer should also include some "discussion" about what OP is asking otherwise...where is the value of an answer? Provide a bad code example just to "_literally answer the question_?) 2) To be pedantic you may want to consider ?: as an if and I **wouldn't** suggest to use ternary operator here... 3) If they don't know |= then probably they should go back to read MSDN (it is worth to mention that for bool operands it is **logical OR**, not a bitwise OR...)

Comment: @JeroenMostert I agree (I don't want to even start to consider 1) non trivial property getters and 2) microoptimizations when talking for _safe of discussion_, I added a note back to your comment

Comment: Then maybe you shouldn't have mentioned `CMOV` at all, since by then we're already deep into jitter territory. :-) I just wanted to point out the irony of this being the *opposite* of an optimization if `a` is not a simple local.

Comment: You're right, should add that getter is trivial, inlined by JIT compiler and bla bla bla...far too much for this answer!

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti You are right about the |= operator working with nullables and also about it not being a bitwise operator; excuse my for having use an aggressive tone :( ... About discussing and all that, I don't agree. If the OP says he knows an If solves it and he wants answers to avoid using an if, you should go with that. This is the first phrase on the SO tour: "This site is all about getting answers. It's not a discussion forum. There's no chit-chat."

Comment: @daniloquio don't worry, `a |= b` expands to `a = a || b `and when it involves nullables it's not immediate to understand the implications, if `b` is `false` then `a` is unchanged - not `false` (that's why I'd go with the `if`). about discussion: hmmmmm when I do not agree with the solution I suggest (like in this case, BTW) I'd also try to explain why but well, it's a POV, I suppose

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this using [conditional operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28.aspx):

```
status = logicBeingTested.isItTrue ? true : status;
```

But I do think as other commented that if will be better for clarity:

```
if (logicBeingTested.isItTrue)
{
    status = true;
}
```

Comment: lol that's clever but if status is null to begin with then an error would be thrown right?

Comment: No, in this case status will stay null as it was before.

Comment: I'd say the first one is the usual solution, it works and what's most important, it reflects the intended logic with full clarity. If this thing is true, change 'status'; else, leave it untouched.

Comment: @daniloquio I think this is a matter of taste, for me and you the first option is perfectly clear, but for others the traditional if may be clearer.

Comment: Agree, I'd go with the if myself, but the OP said the If solution is ruled out for the sake of the argument. First solution should be the accepted one: if supports nullable, which the currently accepted answer does not support.

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti You're right, it works with nullables. I was totally confused over this operator and nullables. I'm sorry!